определите член предложения!
возник вопрос про составные именные сказуемые и не только…
«она выглядела красивой» выглядела красивой-составное именно сказуемое. подлежащее и его характеристика собственно.
«она сделала ее красивой» вот тут и загвоздка. «красивой» будет являться сис или это уже определение?


Она выглядела красивой.

Это составное именное сказуемое, выглядела — полузнаменательная связка), красивой — именная часть, выраженная прилагательным в форме Т. п. Нетрудно заметить, что  Т. падежом прилагательного  управляет глагол: выглядела (какой?) красивой, а по роду и числу именная часть согласуется с подлежащим.
Итак, красивой — это именная часть сказуемого.

Она сделала ее красивой. Она сделала его красивым.

Здесь ситуация аналогичная, но согласование определения по роду и числу делается не с подлежащим, а с дополнением. Глагол же задает определению Т.п.
Она сделала ее (какой?) красивой. Она сделала его (каким?) красивым. Это определение.
